# Do I have to manually make a new local database for each new rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Newbie question.

I set up a rails app to use postrges locally, which took me awhile.

Of course I had to fill in the database.yml file with the database details, but I was doing that in the manner of a mechanical zombie, just typing in what I thought would work without understanding why I was doing it.

What I don't understand is whether the database was created with the rails app when I executed `rails new myProject`, or if the database was created independently during the postrgres installation and then connected to by the app.

The result is that I'm not sure whether, upon creating a second app with `rails new mySecondProject`, I need to go and somehow create a second database for it to connect to, or whether it does that on its own and the info I put in the database.yml file is just to give it access to my local.....postgres program....or something like that.

Is this making sense??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the database is not created when you create a new rails app. However you can create the database using the rake task `rake db:create`.

To see the list of all tasks in namespace 'db' you can run `rake -T db`.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you migrate correctly to PG, Rails will do this automatically next time.

Give the [Railscast: #342 Migrating to PostgreSQL](http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql) a look.